# Git reset --hard on local repository, on remote as well?

Tags: git, github

When i do `git reset --hard <some commit>` on my local repository will my remote repository also be reset to that commit when i push to the remote?

Answer (score 7):

Doing a hard reset to a particular commit moves your local branch pointer to point at that commit, and then sets your local working copy to match the repository at that commit.

When you next run `git push`, git will *attempt* to tell the remote server to move its branch pointer to point at the same commit - but the server will probably refuse, saying that this is not a "fast-forward". That's because moving that branch pointer on a shared repository can be dangerous - it may make the old history inaccessible, and other people may have different changes based on the old history.

To tell the remote repository that you're OK with those risks, run `git push --force-with-lease` (older instructions will say to use `git push --force`; the "with lease" essentially checks for somebody else pushing at the same time as you).

Answer (score 2):

No, that will only affect the local repository. But, you'll likely get a merge conflict when you attempt to push to remote and the remote might reject it.

`git reset` is destructive. If you want to "undo" something in a shared repo, you likely need to use `git revert` to create an *additional* commit to revert the changes, rather than undoing changes.

If however this isn't a shared repository, and you're okay destroying upstream work, then you can use git reset as mentioned and then use git push `--force` to destroy remote work and make it match your local repo.

edit: hadn't finished typing when I hit submit